# search in foursquare users api with name and location

Tags: foursquare

i need to search in foursquare API for user and add location in search not just name but the API docs didn't have location option although in normal search in site we can add location in users search with name.

Answer (score 0):

The [user/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search) is designed to help users find friends on Foursquare, not find users at a location. You can call the [herenow](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) endpoint to see if friends are at a specific venue.